# Run automated UI test on Azure VM triggered via pipeline

Tags: azure, ui-testing

We have a very complex (non-web, .NET) software system wherefore we started to create automated UI tests as the last step of the test pyramid. These tests are mostly end-2-end tests between different parts of the system based on UIA3 and FlaUI. Let's call them use-case-tests.

Now the idea is to have an Azure VM pre-provisioned with the system, deploy regularly the (newly developed) UI tests to that machine and run them there.
(side note: currently, we like to avoid the regular rollout of the system itself, because of the complexity. Once in a quarter is good enough for the system. More interesting is to grow the UI test suite and get its use-case-tests automatical running.)

Inside an Azure build pipeline, we run some fundamental unit-test of our UI test suite itself (addressing only basic non-UI functions we use in the use-case-tests). Then we copy the build artifacts (the assemblies with the use-case-tests and the xUnit console runner) to the Azure VM with the pre-installed software system).

So far everything was straight forward. But how we can run the use-case-tests there? To run the applications (WinForms/WPF apps) it needs an interactive session. There is not clear for me how to remotely interactive login, trigger tests, ...).

Any help, hints, ideas are very appreciated.

Thanks, Marko

Answer (score 0):

## Solution (Draft, PoC)

After some investigations and a lot of try and error, a draft of a solution is this:

- copy all your artifacts to deploy in a folder (e.g. project-root/deploy)
  I use FAKE for my build environment and it looks like that:

  ```ml
  Target.create "Provide-Deployment-Package" (fun _ ->
      // Setup some constants for later usage
      let outputDir = projectRootDir </> "src" </> "UseCaseTests" </> "UseCaseTests" </> "bin" </> configuration
      let xUnitRunnerDir = projectRootDir </> "packages" </> "tests" </> "xunit.runner.console" </> "tools" </> "net472"
      let xUnitTestAdapter = projectRootDir </> "packages" </> "tests" </> "xunit.runner.visualstudio" </> "build" </> "_common"
      let deployDir = projectRootDir </> "deploy"

      Directory.ensure(deployDir) |> ignore

      Shell.copyRecursiveTo true deployDir outputDir |> ignore
      Shell.copyRecursiveTo true deployDir xUnitRunnerDir |> ignore
      Shell.copyRecursiveTo true deployDir xUnitTestAdapter |> ignore
  )
  ```
- add a publish task in your (yaml) build pipeline

  ```
  - publish: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/deploy
    artifact: UC-Test-Artifacts
  ```
- create a token for later usage from an agent

  - goto `https://dev.azure.com/{your-organization}/_usersSettings/tokens
  - create a new token with necessary permissions
    (I have used `Full Access` but this is not a good idea!)
  - store the created toke for later usage
    (something like `vn6yseuyq2brbgze3rylo...`
  - see also [Authenticate with a personal access token (PAT)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops#authenticate-with-a-personal-access-token-pat)
- create an Agent Pool

  - goto `https://dev.azure.com/{your-organization)/_settings/agentpools`
  - add a pool, e.g. name it `bvms`
- create an Agent

  - click `New Agent`
  - follow the instruction of the opened dialog `Get the Agent`
    (run it on your VM where later the UI tests should run)
- configure a release pipeline with 2 Agent jobs

  - Agent 1:
  - Agent Pool: `Azrue Pipelines`
  - Agent Specification: `vs2017-win2016`
  - Artifact download: `UC-Test-Artifacts`
  - Agent 2:
  - Agent Pool: `bvms`
  - Agent Specification: `vs2017-win2016`
  - Artifact download: `UC-Test-Artifacts`
- Steps of Agent 1:

  - Azure file copy
  - Source: `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/UC-Test-Artifacts/UC-Test-Artifacts`
  - Destination Type: `Azure VM`
  - Credential of an admin account of your VM
  - Destination Folder: `c:\_temp`
- Steps of Agent 2:

  - Power Shell Script
  - Script: `c:\_temp\xunit.console.exe c:\_temp\Bvms.UiAutomation.UseCaseTests.dll`

> Remark: the step of copying the artifacts to the VM might be replaced with options behind the publishing mechanism.

## Some resources

- [UI testing considerations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/ui-testing-considerations?view=azure-devops&tabs=mstest)
- [Pipeline artifacts in Azure Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)
- [Azure Pipelines agents - Interactive vs. service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#interactive-or-service)
- [Self-hosted Windows agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops)
- [Agent Download](https://vstsagentpackage.azureedge.net/agent/2.160.1/vsts-agent-win-x64-2.160.1.zip)
- [Windows Application Driver](https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver)
- [WinAppDriver in CI with Azure Pipelines](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver/wiki/WinAppDriver-in-CI-with-Azure-Pipelines)
- [Run UWP appium tests in azure pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57743995/run-uwp-appium-tests-in-azure-pipeline)